# 2 выбранных элемента в меню вместо 1-го

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-menu

Делаю такое меню в `NavigationView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="Import" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Tools" />
</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share"
                android:checked="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

</menu>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при старте был выбран элемент `Share`, для этого прописал

```
android:checked="true"
```

При запуске получаю следующую картину[image]

Когда нажимаю на элемент `Send`, показывает выбранным 2 элемента:[image]

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: В коде при клике по айтему пропишите `navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.itemID);` Должно сработать...

Comment: первому элементу вы в разметке прописали быть выделенным, вот он и выделенный всегда теперь

Comment: @DevOma спасибо, все заработало. Считаю ваше решение лучшим.

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи, просто помечайте необходимый элемент меню выбранным программно. Только не забудьте, пожалуйста, перед этим удалить строку android:checked="true" в разметке.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_navigation_view);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(5).setChecked(true);
```

После этого, если правильно обрабатывать нажатия в navigationView с помощью NavigationItemSelectedListener, все должно работать как надо.

Comment: Можно и так, только 2-ая строчка немного некорректна, т.к. у нас 5-ый элемент "Communicate", имеет вложенное меню. Корректно будет так: navigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).getSubMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true); И потом обрабатывать нажатия в NavigationItemSelectedListener. Но проще сделать, как сказал @DevOma - прописать только navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.itemID);